# Material-UI textfield and textlabel

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm always a late adopter so this is my first time working with Material-ui and I love the aesthetics of it, but it's a lot more finicky than other UI frameworks I've used.

I have just a simple sign in 'card'. Just an email and password form, with a checkbox and a button. It looks great for the most part, but it's driving me nuts that the textfield label transition and animation works when it wants to. Right now the textfield label ends up shrunken on the top as if the input was focused, even when it's not... and then randomly it will work in the first input, but not the password input.
For the life of me I've tried every  approach I can think of. My code is pasted below, and please if there's something else that might help diagnose this disorder let me know and I'll post that too.

```
 <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="login_email_input"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
            classes={{ root: classes.textFieldRoot }}
            value={formData.email}
            // value=""
            // InputLabelProps={{
            //   shrink: inputState.email,
            //   // shrink: false,
            // }}
            onSelect={(e) => setInputState({ email: true, password: false })}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            autofocus
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="login_password_input"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            classes={{ root: classes.textFieldRoot }}
            value={formData.password}
            // InputLabelProps={{
            //   focused: inputState.password,
            //   shrink: !Boolean(inputState.password),
            // }}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            onSelect={(e) => setInputState({ email: false, password: true })}
          />
         <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox
                value={formData.rememberMe}
                name="rememberMe"
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                color="primary"
                disabled={!validated}
              />
            }
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            classes={{ root: classes.submit, label: classes.buttonText }}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
    </form>
```

Comment: I just created a code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-textfield-cc2uj) consisting on 2 text fields, i.e. first one is email and other is password. As you might notice, the `email` label might be at the top, as if the field is focused, because it has a prop `autoFocus`. here is the link of text field [props](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/), where `autoFocus` prop says 

`If true, the input element will be focused during the first mount.`

Comment: Also, your code is using two versions of the `autoFocus` in the email field and `autofocus` with lowercase `f` in the password text field. Although the one with capital `F` is a valid prop.

Comment: Your code also includes `InputLabelProps`, which could also make the label already in shrink state.

Comment: Also, if the text field is mounted with a default value or the value prop has some text in it, it'll be displayed in the shrink state.